# LVP flooring in a room with a concrete wall

Tags: concrete, flooring, vinyl-flooring

I'm thinking about installing LVP in a room in my basement that has a concrete wall. All tutorials I've watched talk about hiding the space between the walls and the floor panels with baseboard moulding (optionally with 1/4" rounds).

Two related questions based on this:

1. Is this expansion space necessary against the concrete wall or would the space against the drywall on the other side of the room be sufficient?
2. I won't know until I start, but if the concrete wall isn't perfectly straight, I'll naturally end up with gaps. From what I've read, the 1/4" rounds are supposed to help with this when working against drywall. Any way to hide these imperfections when it comes to a concrete wall?

If it matters, the rest of the walls are all drywall. The concrete wall is on the long side of the room.

Comment: Not as much securing as covering up a small expansion space you are suppose to leave between floor and wall.  If it needs to be held down, something is very wrong.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Any advice on how to cover up the expansion space? Is it okay to just leave expansion space on the other side of the room? I'll also update my question based on this :)

Comment: Should be construction adhesives to mount moulding to cement.  Need to start with straight line because flooring does not bend. Expansion space should not be large(think around 1/8 to 1/4 inch).  Need to check cement for straightness, since that might cause problems with finishing.

Comment: The expansion question should be answered by the instructions that come with your flooring. In theory, if you need a 1/4" gap all the way around, leaving a 1/2" gap on only one side _should_ be sufficient. **However**, if there are objects (like furniture) sitting on the flooring, that may impact the floor's ability to move past the weighted point, and, therefore the gap on only one side might not be sufficient. I'd follow @crip659's advice and attach whatever baseboard/trim molding you're going to use to the concrete with some adhesive and have the gap all the way around.